# php code is showing instead of running

Tags: php

i am using php 5.2.4 with wampserver. everything is going fine. i have done several works in a few days. there were no problem.

But i am facing a peculiar problem. the script i wrote for the page is showing instead of rendered web page. my page is given here:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "abdrhm30@yahoo.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

     echo "<br>";
     echo $email_from + $email_to + $email_message;
      echo "<br>";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
}
?>
```

when i run this from phpmyadmin it shows 0 on the left top corner of the page.
 i have checked short_tag , restarted server twice. but no result. what can i do?

Comment: what is the file name of your page ?

Comment: wait.. what do you mean by "when i run this from phpmyadmin"? You are running those code inside a phpmyadmin?

Comment: what does your add_handler directives look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing how string concatenation works with javascript. I mean this line:

```
echo $email_from + $email_to + $email_message;
```

Replace it with

```
echo $email_from . $email_to . $email_message;
```

Comment: thanks, that was my mistake. but this doesn't help to recover the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make a file phpinfo.php and add the following code to it:

```
phpinfo();
```

If still you are able to see the code, reinstall your wampserver and make sure Apache server is running.

Comment: forgot to mention, run the phpinfo.php file after you upload it to your root folder

Comment: Then may be your wampserver is not configured correctly. Try reinstalling it and make sure the Apache service is running. Your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

check for whitespaces

also - remove the ?>  from the end of your PHP file, that can also cause output errors